# Creating new polymorphic relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel application how can I with the following setup create new parents and children?

```
class Parent extends Model
{
    public function extended()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Child extends Model 
{
    public function extendedFrom()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Parent', 'extended');
    }
}

class CreateParentsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('parents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('extended_id');
            $table->string('extended_type');
        });
    }
}

class CreateChildrenTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('id');
        });

        Schema::table('children', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('id')
                ->references('extended_id')->on('parents')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
$parent = new Parent();
$parent->save();
$child = new Child();
$parent->extended()->save($child);
```

But that gives the following error

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2161:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the API here https://laravel.com/api/5.2/ and search for `morphTo`, you can see that it returns a `MorphTo` object.  https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphTo.html

If you then look through the methods on this class, you can see that there is no `save` method on this class.  The method you are probably looking for is `associate`

With that said, try the following.

```
$parent->extended()->associate($child);
```

Your schema also seems to be broken.  `extended_id` can't be your primary key (which was automatically set via the `increments` function) and the id of the child.  It needs an `id` column which is `auto_incrementing` and remove `auto_incrementing` from `extended_id`.

Think about it this way, this is polymorphic so multiple types of children can potentially have the same `id`s.  In this case, each parent could only possibly have 1 child because the `extended_id` column is unique.

By adding the `id` column, making it primary key and auto incrementing and setting `extended_id` to just `unsigned not null` worked for me and it's saving appropriately.

I'd also take a look into your database settings.  What you had previously should have been generating SQL errors because it should not have been possible with the foreign key you had setup.  You may be ignoring foreign key checks somewhere.

Comment: Using what I wrote with `$parent->extended()->associate($child);` instead of `$parent->extended()->save($child);` followed with `$parent->save()` results in a new parent with id 0 and no child created.

Comment: Also adding `$child->extendedFrom()->save($parent)` and `$child->save()` adds the child but the id is always 0 even though the parent column is a auto increment column.

Comment: `associate` must not save the `child`.  After you associate, try `$child->save()`

Comment: Like I said in my second comment, saving the child creates the child but the id is always 0 on both the child and the parent.

Comment: I have set it up like you suggested and it works correctly, though I had to remove the foreign keys. Is it possible to have a foreign key from `child.id` to `parent.extended_id`? With the current solution the parent is first inserted, then the child and then the `extended_id` and `extended_type` are updated. The foreign key error is triggered when the child is inserted (since the `extended_id` is 0 at that moment)

Comment: You have to remember this is a polymorphic relation so you will potentially have many different types of `child`.  If you relate all these different types of `child.id` to the `parent.extended_id` column via FK, from the database' perspective, it won't know which type of `child` to cascade the deletes to when a parent is deleted.